# Why doesn't php7 catch Throwable when require fails?

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to catch a require fatal error (https://3v4l.org/5MV3I):

```
try {
    require("foo");
}
catch (Throwable $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

However the script dies in all php versions:

```
Warning: require(foo): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /in/5MV3I on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'foo' (include_path='.:') in /in/5MV3I on line 4

Process exited with code 255.
```

The docs say (http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php):

> ...except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error.

What types of php7 fatal errors are catchable and which ones aren't?

Comment: Fatal errors are unrecoverable by definition. There's no point in them being catchable.

Comment: if you want a more graceful failure, you could use `include()` instead.

Comment: Ones that will prevent the code from even being parsed will not be catchable because parsing happens before the code is run. This is why the require one ain't: that occurs whilst PHP is still assembling the code, and before it attempts to run any of it. I can't find any docs which describe the separation of the two types of error (ie: compilation and runtime).

Comment: @Sammitch imho this general statement is plain wrong for php7. At least the php docs are not clear about what a "fatal" error is and its not present in the Error class hierarchy. On the other hand side fatal means fatal- only there's no docs which ones are fatal. Imho adam uncovered the reason for this specific error case.

Comment: Well think of it like this: You can recover your program from a fatal error just as easily as you can physically recover from a fatal injury.

Comment: Php7 knows catchable and non-catchable fatal errors, so rhis comparison misses the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "require()" to include a file. You are requiring it. If it not exists it ends in a Compile Error. PHP then aborts. The idea is, that you use require on critical files. If those are missing, it aborts immediately.

If you want to catch something, you have to go with "include()". Here you can catch a success quite easy:

```
$includeResult = include("foo");
if (!$includeResult) {
    // you will land here, if include did not work.
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, I've made the question more explicit.

Comment: @andig well, this is not documented that nice. But almost every fatal error, is not catchable. Maybe the error docs help you more: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php